# Foreach file in root directory and all sub directories

Tags: php, file, include

I want to `include` every file from every directory in my project. What I currently have is, that I `include` every file from a specific directory

```
foreach (glob("*.php") as $filename)
{
    include_once $filename;
}
```

But I also want to do the same for every directory I have and all the files in there. I heard of the `__autoload` function, but I also need it sometimes in for non-class-functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[On this man page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php), the first comment gives a function that lists all the files recursively. Just adapt it to match your needs:

```
<?php
function include_all_php_files($dir)
{
    $root = scandir($dir);
    foreach($root as $value)
    {
        if($value === '.' || $value === '..') {continue;}
        if(is_file("$dir/$value") && preg_match('#\.php$#', $value))
        {
            include_once ("$dir/$value");
            continue;
        }
        include_all_php_files("$dir/$value");
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is your friend.

```
/**
 * @param string path to the root directory 
 */
function include_files($dir) {
    foreach (glob($dir . "/*") as $file) {
        if(is_dir($file)){
           include_files($file);
        } else {
           include_once($file);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey. What exactly does include_files do? Because it tells me unknown function `include_files`

Comment: That's impossible. But anyway, if you don't understand recursion, please use @jerska's answer. It works out of the box. Mine is very crude because I assumed that you could adapt the idea to your need.

Comment: My answer is also a recursive function actually.

Comment: @Jerska Yes, I know. It's just that yours work right away with filetype checking. And I honestly don't know why he got include_files undefined.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he didn't entirely copy/paste your function, bacause it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This works for me.

```
$accepted_extension = array("jpeg", "jpg", "gif", "bmp", "png");
$return = array();

$results = scandir($folder);
foreach ($results as $result) {
    if ($result == '.' or $result == '..')
        continue;
    else if (is_dir($folder . '/' . $result))
        continue;
    else {
        $extn = substr($result, strpos($result, ".") + 1);
        if (in_array($extn, $accepted_extension)) {
            $return[] = $result;
        }
    }
}
```